# Maven release issue in Jenkins

Tags: maven, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to taking maven build & update release using Jenkins. I am not able to update the project version , getting error. How to fix this ?

> 

### Jenkins version : 2.7.1 WAR Maven : 3 Windows 7

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:username/test-app.git</connection>
    <url>scm:git:git@github.com:username/test-app.git</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:username/test-app.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>
```

Maven Goal

-X release:clean release:prepare release:perform

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project test-app: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Host key verification failed.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by Adding SSH key in my GitHub. followed below mentioned YouTube Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5qNpRGB7Qw

Answer (score 1):

I generally see this because the Jenkins job runs with a different account (or the system account, on Windows) than the account having the private key.

You must make sure the Jenkins job (check its environment variables) has a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` (or `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`) with the right private ssh key (preferably without passphrase, to avoid the all pageant passphrase cache issue).

You can add an `ssh -Tv git@github.com` build step, just for testing.

Comment: you mean that i am running Jenkins job using admin/admin. But Github is not accepting the Jenkins job user to check-in the code. How to fix this ? I am using Windows 7

Comment: As I mention, check your environment variables, and add the ssh -Tv, to see where it seeks the private key.

Comment: which environment variable ? guide me

Comment: Username, you will see it in one of your past job , link environment variables

Comment: running my jenkins jobs using "gnana" as user. guide me what variable and   how to link in env ?

Comment: See this as an example: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin?focusedCommentId=70877479#comment-70877479

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand what your trying to give solution to my problem ?. Better you can give full steps to resolve my issue

Comment: @Gnana See the picture: it illustrates how you can see what USERNAME is used when Jenkins executes your job: click on a past job then on the link as shown in the picture.

Comment: My job doesn't have Environment Variable link, But log shows that "Started by user Gnanapandithn Murugesan"